# Generating comma separated string not working

Tags: c#, excel, csv, asp.net-web-api

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "csv")]
public Stream GetCollectionAsCsv()
{
    string[] myValues = { "test", "test","test" };
    string csvString = string.Join(",", myValues);

    byte[] csvBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvString);


    if (WebOperationContext.Current != null)
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/csv";
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"testss.csv\"";
    }


    return new MemoryStream(csvBytes);

}
```

when I run this code I was be able to download csv file by although I am adding commas to cvs string excel file putting all data into a single column

```
**OUTPUT EXCEL**

ROW A | ROW B | ROW C

test,test,test | NOTHING | NOTHING 


**My Expectation**

ROW A | ROW B | ROW C

test|test|test
```

Comment: How are you consuming the memory stream?

Comment: @Brandon calling web api method by /products/csv then browser starts downloadin csv file as I pointed Content-Disposition as a csv file

Answer (score 0):

Most likely related to the regional settings. Try replacing comma with a semicolon:

```
string csvString = string.Join(";", myValues);
```

For more options please refer to this page:
http://kb.paessler.com/en/topic/2293-i-have-trouble-opening-csv-files-with-microsoft-excel-is-there-a-quick-way-to-fix-this

E.g. you can try adding
sep=,
as the very first line in your CSV file

Or change your regional settings to make sure comma is a list separator